# Where Should i keep my jar files so that All projects commonly used them?

Tags: java, linux, apache, spring-mvc, tomcat

> I Have to deploy 40 to 50 Spring Mvc project  on Linux server  So
>   every project must contains Spring  jar file in its lib folder
>
> Is there any way to keep all jar file at one one place so that all the
>   projects could use
>
> I have tried to placed all file in Apache-tomcat's lib folder and
>   remove Spring's jar file from the Spring MVC's project lib folder
>
> But after that all the url stop working and i didn't get any exception
>   and i also compile all java files by using the

```
javac -cp :/path of Apache-tomcat's lib/*.jar: className.java
```

> I didnt get any exception all filed compiled successfully
>
> If anyone knows how can i managed these jar files then please let me
>   know
>
> Should i need to define the path in projects files like web.xml or
>   meta-inf  So that When the projects run it automatically find the jar
>   at some specific place...

Answer (score 0):

- When you deploy web application to production server (Apache Tomcat in this case), you don't copy any JAR file for application working, because application packaged in WAR file format.
- If you want using many Spring-based web applications for development, testing purpose, you also don't need copy JAR files many times. Use Gradle or Maven dependencies management tool. (You maybe need covert legacy project to new project structure when use new generation build tools like Gralde, Maven).